# Not able to send/receive email from Jenkins using Email-ext plugin

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins ver. 1.463 running on 32-bit Windows Server. I have installed Email-ext plugin version 2.30.2.

I am unable to get any email notifications.

What i am trying to do - is send an email after every job - irrespective of whether the operation is success, failure, abort, not-build, etc..
I am using Jenkins to run Automated Test Suites.

The way i have configured a test job is "In the Post-Build Actions , have selected Editable Email Notification", and filled in the required fields(recipient list,etc). In the Advanced - selected all the triggers from dropdown such as "Success, Failure, Aborted, Regression, Fixed, Not-Built, Stable.

i have verified the smtp server, recipients, Still I am unable to get any email,
 in the Console Output of the job i see the following lines

> Email was triggered for: Success
>   Sending email for trigger: Success.

In the Jenkins Server, in the "jenkins.err.log", see the following error message / exception being thrown, but dont know the exact cause

> > Aug 27, 2013 5:41:57 PM hudson.model.Run run 
> >     INFO: TestJob-for-Email #7 main build action completed: SUCCESS
> >     Aug 27, 2013 5:41:58 PM hudson.model.Executor run
> >     SEVERE: Executor threw an exception
> >     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getPreviousBuild()Lhudson/model/AbstractBuild;
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.content.BuildStatusContent.evaluate(BuildStatusContent.java:71)
> >      at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.DataBoundTokenMacro.evaluate(DataBoundTokenMacro.java:177)
> >      at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expand(TokenMacro.java:177)
> >      at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:219)
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.ContentBuilder.transformText(ContentBuilder.java:63)
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.setSubject(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:687)
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.createMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:485)
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:319)
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:311)
> >      at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:271)
> >      at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
> >      at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
> >      at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:685)
> >      at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1018)
> >      at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1478)
> >      at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
> >      at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
> >      at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)

Could someone please help,Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade Jenkins.  Your version is too old for the version of the `email-ext` plugin that you're using.  See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18728

Comment: Hi,I am using Jenkins ver.1.573 Still facing same issue With Email-ext plugin version 2.38.1. `error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(Lhudson/model/AbstractBuild;Lhudson/model/TaskListener;Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/util/List;)Ljava/lang/String;`

Comment: Thanks Jeff, updating the Jenkins resolved the issue. Sorry for late acknowledgement :)